# I lost my Android, am I able to recover my contacts onto the new one?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery, lost-phone

I lost my galaxy s5 active a day ago and have a next generation phone being shipped. Is there anyway through android or through at&t that I can recover my contacts from my old phone even though it's since been lost and shut off?

Answer (score 1):

If you were signed into a google account, all your contacts should be automatically backed up.  When you sign into the same google account on the new phone, the contacts will be there.